# proper use of sort by scandir()?

Tags: c, sorting, scandir

This is my compare function...

```
int nameSort(const struct dirent** file1, const struct dirent** file2){

    char* a = *file1 -> d_name;
    char* b = *file2 -> d_name;
    //printf("comparing %s     AND    %s\n", a, b);
    return strcasecmp(a,b);
}
```

am error: request for member ‘d_name’ in something not a structure or union
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) of `->` member selection via pointer operator is higher over `*` defense operator, so

```
 *file1->d_name;
```

should  be:

```
 (*file1)-> d_name;
```